# How do I create multiple so files to be included in APK?

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build multiple .so libraries which must be included as separate libraries in the APKs 'lib' folder. How do I accomplish that using cmake and gradle?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code  If you have already read that and found something unclear, then please specify exacly where you got stuck and show what your current makefile(s) and build.gradle looks like.

Comment: @Michael Your advice is just as useful as this one: Please see the internet and use Google.